# Перевернуть строку в скобках регулярным выражением

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, строки

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Дана строка, и надо перевернуть только те фрагменты строки, которые находятся в круглых скобках. Python. Для наглядности:

"h(el)lo" >> "h(le)lo";

"h(lle)o W(lro)d" >> "h(ell)o W(orl)d"

Я делаю следующим образом:

re.sub(r"\b[a-zA-Z ]+\b", lambda m:m.group(0)[::-1], stroka)

Но данная регулярка переворачивает все символы - и в скобках и без.
"one two (three) four" >> "owt eno (eerht) ruof"

Comment: Какой язык программирования?

Comment: Язык программирования Python

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку решения и что не получилось. Иначе его закроют как учебный. Спасибо.

Comment: ну так да, вы же не определили группы в регулярном выражении, если групп нет - то вся регулярка это одна группа

Answer (score 3):

Пара `\(`, `\)` - это просто скобки в строке. `([^)]*)` - группа символов внутри скобок. Принимаются любые символы кроме закрывающей скобки. Группу можно получить внутри lambda-выражения в виде `m.group(1)`:

```
re.sub(r'\(([^)]*)\)', lambda m: f'({m.group(1)[::-1]})', 'h(lle)o W(lro)d')
```

> ```
> 'h(ell)o W(orl)d'
> ```

Comment: Я восхищаюсь. Спасибо. Мне регулярки пока не даются.

Comment: Станислав, а подскажите что надо добавить в код, что бы  переворот осуществлялся и во вложенных скобках. Пример:
"one (two (three) four)" >> "one (rouf (eerht) owt)"

Comment: Я не возьмусь регулярными выражениями обрабатывать вложенные скобочные структуры. Если вложенность не ограничена - это невозможно в принципе. Если ограничиться, скажем, двумя уровнями вложенности, то это возможно, но сложно.

Comment: Да, там вложенность неограниченная. Получается на базе этого регулярного выражения, надо создавать рекурсивную функцию?

Comment: Да, цикл со стеком - всё что нужно. Рекурсия не обязательна, без неё будет проще. Но это уже тема для другого вопроса.